# WPF Mouse down event no Coordinates

Tags: wpf, mousedown

I am using WPF mouse down event on a control. I want to get the X,Y coordinates but I am getting an error:

```
private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      double x = e.X, double y = e.Y;
}
```

I could not access the coordinates. I wonder why. Can Someone help? If mouse down is unable to get the coordinates, is there other way I can get the coordinate of the cursor when click?

Comment: what error do you get? Please post more details and information

Answer (score 48):

You need to use the [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition.aspx) method to retrieve the point.

```
private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(this);
    double x = p.X;
    double y = p.Y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
C#
private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        double x = e.GetPosition("Name of your element" as IInputElement).X;
    }
```